# Azure Data Factory: Unrecognized expression: &grant_type=client_credentials'

Tags: powerbi, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, access-token

Does anyone know why data factory does not like the expression that I'm trying to use here?
It's purpose is to retrieve ADD token based on secret, tenant ID and client ID, as per the following tutorial to automate PowerBI data refresh using ADF: https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2022/03/refresh-power-bi-datasets-with-adf-or.html

Super grateful for any pointers!

```
@concat(
    'client_id='
    , activity('Get ClientId From AKV').output.value
    , '&scope=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'
    , '&client_secret='
    , activity('Get Secret From AKV').output.value
    , &grant_type=client_credentials'
    )
```

Error message:  Position 226 Unrecognized expression: &grant_type=client_credentials'

Comment: Because  you missed the apostrophe on that line.

Comment: absolute legend! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Andrey! Added the apostrophe and it's worked!

```
@concat(
    'client_id='
    , activity('Get ClientId From AKV').output.value
    , '&scope=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'
    , '&client_secret='
    , activity('Get Secret From AKV').output.value
    , '&grant_type=client_credentials'
    )
```